# How to create a dictionary if value contain a particular string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary below

- Fist i need to check a parent which contain `Main` or `Contract`.
- FOr Main add `name` to the level1 dictionary and Contract level2 dictionary

```
    d = {"employee": [
          {
            "id": "18",
            "name": "Manager",
            "parent": "Main level"
          },
          {
            "id": "19",
            "name": "Employee",
            "parent": "Main level"
          },
          {
            "id": "32",
            "name": "Contract",
            "parent": "Contract level"
          },
              {
            "id": "21",
            "name": "Admin",
            "parent": "Main level"
          },
        ]}
```

Expected out is below

```
 {"employee": [
    {'level1':['Manager','Employee']},
    {'level2':['Test','HR']},
      {
        "id": "18",
        "name": "Manager",
        "parent": "Main level"
      },
      {
        "id": "19",
        "name": "Employee",
        "parent": "Main level"
      },
      {
        "id": "32",
        "name": "Test",
        "parent": "Contract level"
      },
          {
        "id": "21",
        "name": "HR",
        "parent": "Contract level"
      },
    ]}
```

Code

```
d['level1'] = {}
d['level2'] = {}
for i,j in d.items():
  #check parent is Main 
  if j['parent'] in 'Main':
      d['level1'] = j['name']
  if j['parent'] in 'Contract':
      d['level2'] = j['name']
```

I got the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: The error is happening because `d.items()` has only one value and it is a list. Tkey key for that value is "employee".

Comment: why your expected dictionary contains different values for `name`.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the input_data and expected_output. Fix it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is misguided.

You made 3 mistakes:

1. You tried looping over the parent dict instead of the actual list of employees.
2. You are using `x in y` backwards, for checking if one string contains another.
3. You are not actually appending new names to the "levels" lists.

Try this:

```
d["level1"] = []
d["level2"] = []
for j in d["employee"]:
    # check parent is Main
    if "Main" in j["parent"]:
        d["level1"] += [j["name"]]
    if "Contract" in j["parent"]:
        d["level2"] += [j["name"]]
```

That will give you the "levels" as dict "siblings" of the employees (instead of in the list of employees, which is what you actually want).

To get the *exact* result you want, you would have to do something like this:

```
level1 = []
level2 = []
for j in d["employee"]:
    # check parent is Main
    if "Main" in j["parent"]:
        level1 += [j["name"]]
    if "Contract" in j["parent"]:
        level2 += [j["name"]]

d["employee"] = [{"level1": level1}, {"level2": level2}] + d["employee"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dd = {'Main level': 'level1', 'Contract level': 'level2'}

res = {}
for x in d['employee']:
    k = dd[x['parent']]
    if k in res:
        res[k].append(x['name'])
    else:
        res[k] = [x['name']]

d['employee'] = [{k: v} for k, v in res.items()] + d['employee']
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'employee': [{'level1': ['Manager', 'Employee', 'Admin']},
  {'level2': ['Contract']},
  {'id': '18', 'name': 'Manager', 'parent': 'Main level'},
  {'id': '19', 'name': 'Employee', 'parent': 'Main level'},
  {'id': '32', 'name': 'Contract', 'parent': 'Contract level'},
  {'id': '21', 'name': 'Admin', 'parent': 'Main level'}]}
```